# Default to Laravel File cache if redis is down

Tags: php, caching, laravel, redis

In the spirit of "[chaos monkey](http://techblog.netflix.com/2012/07/chaos-monkey-released-into-wild.html)" I'm trying to ensure that a laravel application keeps going even when the services it depends on are down.

It uses a DB for primary storage, and a redis cache. What I'd like to do is have it automatically fall back to the file cache if and when redis fails.

I haven't been able to find a clear example.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

One way to solve this problem is to overwrite Laravel's default `Illuminate\Cache\CacheManager`class and alter the ioc binding

```
class MyCacheManager extends Illuminate\Cache\CacheManager
{
    protected function createRedisDriver(array $config)
    {
        try {
            return parent::createRedisDriver($config);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            //Error with redis
            //Maybe there is a more explicit exception ;)
            return $this->resolve('file');
        }
    }
}
```

In some ServiceProvider

```
$this->app->singleton('cache', function($app)
{
    return new MyCacheManager($app);
});
```

This solution will also keep the `Cache` facade working :)

Comment: There is also a package that can helps with this: https://github.com/fingo/laravel-cache-fallback

Answer (score 0):

I just created a package which solves this problem: https://github.com/mathieu-bour/laravel-cache-fallback, if the question is still relevant.

Answer (score -1):

There seems to be a package exactly for this:
https://github.com/xtcat/laravel-redis-fallback

I haven't yet found similar packages for Sessions or Queues. Please share here if anybody has.

Comment: Interesting. Seems to be more recent than my question, worth taking a look at.

Comment: @Scott C, have u found a resolution for ur quest yet, am also after the same thing and i couldnt find any answers to that :(

Comment: Not yet. Still on my to-do list.

Comment: This package is also interesting to get multiple fallback for cache and session: https://github.com/fingo/laravel-cache-fallback / https://github.com/fingo/laravel-session-fallback

Answer (score -1):

Can you not just include an anonymous function in place of the cache driver cnfig setting?

that could try to use Redis and if it fails return file as the setting and Redis if it succeeds

Comment: this is more like a comment than a new answer to the question